# Deleting rows from a structure

Tags: c, arrays, struct

My project was to create a program with a menu that extracts data from a file and arranges it in a structure. Via the menu you are able to insert rows to the end of the structure or delete rows from the structure. The program then copies the structure and saves it to the same file.

So far I have everything working fine except for deleting rows.

Right now my code will just delete the last row of the structure no matter what.

```
else if( input == 3)
{
    int delete;
    printf("Enter row number to be deleted:\n");
    scanf("%i", &delete);

    if( delete > i )
    {
        printf("ERROR: Please enter a valid integer\n");
    }

    strcpy(data[delete].First, data[(delete+1)].First);
    strcpy(data[delete].Last, data[(delete+1)].Last);
    data[delete].Gender = data[(delete+1)].Gender;
    data[delete].Age = data[(delete+1)].Age;
    data[delete].Weight = data[(delete+1)].Weight;
    data[delete].Height = data[(delete+1)].Height;

    i = i - 1;
}
```

The variable `i` is a counter that keeps track of the number of rows in the structure. The code seems to me like it should replace the data of whatever the input delete is and replace it with the data above it in the structure, however it is not working.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: `int delete;` is a very bad idea. Although no sane (and lucky-enough-not-to-be-forced-to-do-so) programmer compiles C code with a C++ compiler, eventually it may happen, and then hell breaks loose.

Comment: you copy only the next element into the one to delete, if your list consist of only 3 elements that will work, if not, you need to put a loop to copy the whole list.

Comment: "however it is not working" - which begs the question.. what *is* it doing? I suspect it is replicating the data from the row above it (so now you have *two* of those), then losing the last item off end due to the reduction of `i`. Sound about right ?

Comment: Yea WhozCraig that's correct. Feel kinda dumb I didn't think of a loop before. Think I have it figured out. Thanks guys.

Comment: @user3072146 Note: if *order* isn't important, swap the *last* element with the one being removed (unless you're removing the last element, obviously), then just decrement `i` by one. No loop required.

Comment: Building on @whozcraig's comment, if you make a list of numbers (indices) of valid rows, then swap a "deleted" index with the "last valid" index and decrement validCount by one, you can make this really efficient. In the end you sort the indices and copy elements into right place, then free the remaining memory

Answer (score 0):

> The variable i is a counter that keeps track of the number of rows …

Since you delete `data[delete]`, the rows are apparently numbered from *0* to *i-1*. The `if` error condition `delete > i` should then rather be `delete >= i`.

> if order isn't important, swap the last element with the one being
>   removed (unless you're removing the last element, obviously), then
>   just decrement i by one. No loop required. – WhozCraig

That's right, of course, albeit there is no point in the part of the swap which copies the element being removed to the position of the last element.

If the order is to be preserved, we can also do without an explicit loop:

```
    memmove(data+delete, data+delete+1, (--i-delete) * sizeof *data);
```